# c# cannot access textboxes from same class

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have two separate questions; however, since they are very similar i will ask them in one posting.

what is the reason i cannot reference the textboxes from here? i created another file in my project and put

```
namespace EnterData.DataEntry
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
```

to make it go into the same namespace and partial class as the webform. but i cannot access the textbox!

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

public class LOMDLL.Main_Lom_Form PopulateMainForm()
        {
            //populate class
            LOMDLL.Main_Lom_Form TheForm = new LOMDLL.Main_Lom_Form();

            try
            {
                TheForm.lom_number = lom_numberTextBox.Text.ToInt();
                TheForm.identified_by = identified_byTextBox.Text;
                TheForm.occurrence_date = occurrence_dateTextBox.Text.ToDateTime();
                //TheForm.pre_contact = pre_contactTextBox.Text; //need to create this texdtbox
                //TheForm.pre_practice_code = pre_practice_codeTextBox.Text; //create this
                TheForm.report_by = report_byTextBox.Text;
                TheForm.report_date = report_dateTextBox.Text.ToDateTime();
                TheForm.section_c_comments = section_c_commentsTextBox.Text;
                TheForm.section_c_issue_error_identified_by = section_c_issue_error_identified_byTextBox.Text;
                TheForm.section_d_investigation = section_d_investigationTextBox.Text;
                TheForm.section_e_corrective_action = section_e_corrective_actionTextBox.Text;
                TheForm.section_f_comments = section_f_commentsTextBox.Text;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
```

i get this error:

Erro`r  20  Cannot access a non-static member of outer type 'EnterData.DataEntry.WebForm1' via nested type 'EnterData.DataEntry.WebForm1.LOMDLL'    C:\Documents and Settings\agordon\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\lomdb\EnterData\DataEntry\DAL.cs 68  38  EnterData`

on all textboxes

what is the reason that i cannot access the textboxes from here?

Comment: There is nothing even remotely legal about `public class LOMDLL.Main_Lom_Form PopulateMainForm()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean to nest classes here?  If you intended to declare a method that returns a `Main_Lom_Form()`, try this:

```
public LOMDLL.Main_Lom_Form PopulateMainForm()
```

If you intended to call that method against a member of `WebForm1` called `TheForm`, then instantiate that outside of the call to `PopulateMainForm`:

```
LOMDLL.Main_Lom_Form TheForm = new LOMDLL.Main_Lom_Form();
public void PopulateMainForm()
{
    // snip
}
```

Comment: thank you, problem is it does not see the Main_Lom_Form (this is a class inside the LOMDLL class

Answer (score 2):

here there is an error:

```
public class LOMDLL.Main_Lom_Form PopulateMainForm()
```

are you declaring this class inside the webform class? anyway the class declaration is wrong.

for the last point of your question, when you have this:

```
public static class Main_Lom_Form
```

imagining you moved out from the other webform class, what is the namespace you have around it (before)? Just play around moving the class inside same namespace than class `WebForm1` and you will not need to put the namespace before the class name, you will be able to create it like this:

```
var obj = new Main_Lom_Form();
```

in case it would make sense, but I doubt ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a few issues with your code.  The first one that pops out is this:

```
public class LOMDLL.Main_Lom_Form PopulateMainForm()
```

That is not a valid line of C# code. I'm assuming you actually meant to write:

```
public LOMDLL.Main_Lom_Form PopulateMainForm()
```

Secondly, if you have defined `Main_Lom_Form` as static, you can't instantiate it, it's a static class. You can address this:

```
public class Main_Lom_Form
```

I think its a combination of the above two issues which is causing the compiler to have a stroke.

Comment: thank you, problem is it does not see the Main_Lom_Form (this is a class inside the LOMDLL class

Comment: Have you suitably imported the type using `using ...`?