# c# instantiating a class problem

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am trying to instantiate classes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using RadarGraphInsertDLL;


namespace EnterData.DataEntry
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void gaia_lom_Inserting(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void SubmitData(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LOMDLL.Main_Lom_Form MainLomFormTable = PopulateMainForm();
            IList<LOMDLL.Lom_Batch> BatchTable = PopulateBatchTable();
            IList<LOMDLL.Lom_Problem> ProblemTable = PopulateProblemTable();
            IList<LOMDLL.Lom_Specimen> SpecimenTable = PopulateSpecimenTable();
        }


    }
}
```

but getting this error:

```
Error   19  The type name 'Main_Lom_Form' does not exist in the type 'EnterData.DataEntry.WebForm1.LOMDLL'  C:\Documents and Settings\agordon\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\lomdb\EnterData\DataEntry\DAL.cs 64  55  EnterData
```

but i do have these!!

```
public class Main_Lom_Form
{
    public int lom_number {get;set;}
    public DateTime occurrence_date {get;set;}
    public DateTime report_date {get;set;}
    public string report_by {get;set;}
    public string identified_by {get;set;}
    public string section_c_issue_error_identified_by{get;set;}
    public string section_c_comments{get;set;}
    public string section_d_investigation{get;set;}
    public string section_e_corrective_action{get;set;}
    public string section_f_comments{get;set;}
    public string pre_practice_code{get;set;}
    public string pre_contact{get;set;}
}
public class Lom_Batch
{
    public int lom_number { get; set; }
    public string batch { get; set; }
}
public class Lom_Problem
{
    public int lom_number { get; set; }
    public string problem { get; set; }
}
public class Lom_Specimen
{
    public int lom_number { get; set; }
    public string specimen { get; set; }
}
```

what is the reason i cannot instantiate the classes?

Comment: You are trying to instantiate a static class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# cannot access textboxes from same class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365754/c-cannot-access-textboxes-from-same-class)

Comment: OP why are you creating two questions for same issue!?

Comment: @i__ did you happen to put the Main_Lom_Form in a namesapce?

Comment: @msar please note that i took out static and still having same issue

Comment: Can you post the namespace that the `Main_Lom_Form` class is in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't giving us the full list of compiler error messages. We can't really help without that. You don't know what the problem is so it's unwise to pick and choose which clues you share

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to assume that there are other compiler errors here that you aren't showing us.  Drop the `static` keyword from the class definition.  You can't instantiate a static class.

Comment: True.  But that generates the error "Cannot create an instance of the static class 'Main_Lom_Form'"

Comment: Actually it wouldn't even get that far... a static class has to have all-static members.  Since none of his members aren't static, the class won't compile.  And that's why his *other* project is complaining about not being able to find it.  It's clear that there are other compiler errors he's encountering but not sharing with us.

Comment: @robe  please note that i took out static and still having same issue

Comment: I'm going to stand by the assertion that you aren't giving us the full list of compiler error messages.  We can't really help without that.  You don't know what the problem is so it's unwise to pick and choose which clues you share.